# Unable to move icon inside the circle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am trying to place `fa-graduation-cap` inside a circle.

So, that means:

```
<span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-4x text-primary"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap fa-2x"></i>
</span>
```

But it doesn't work. The output is this:

[image]

The `graduation-cap` is outside the circle. Why is that?

---

#### Note:

`text-primary` is the bootstrap class for color.

Comment: Why do you think that graduation-cap should be inside the circle in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not applying those classes in the correct way/order.

Following the code from the [examples](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/), here we go.

```html
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

If you want it to be bigger just add a class `fa-2x`, `fa-3x`, `fa-4x` or `fa-5x` to the `span`, nothing else.

Check it on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phaberest/4updc7r3/3/).

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to put the elements together with CSS ?

you probably need to position the icons individually to place them where and how you want them. This could possibly be done with the following:

```
.fa-stack{position: relative;}
.fa-circle{position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;}
.fa-graduation-cap{position:absolute; top: 20px; left: 10px;}
```

you can move the icons over the screen by changing the pixels in the top value and the left value for example.